# UIButton in UITableViewCell selector not being called

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIButton` in a `UITableViewCell` added from Storyboard. When I press on the an action should be called:

```
@IBAction func modifyFavouriteStatus(sender: UIButton) {
    favouriteBool = false
    var emptyHeart = UIImage(named: "Red_Heart_Empty_x23px.png")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
    favouriteButton.setImage(emptyHeart, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

However the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called instead. I want this to be called only when I press on the cell itself, not the button.

P.S. user interaction is enabled on the button

EDIT:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SpotlightCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SpotlightCell

    let userObject = self.objectArray[indexPath.section] as! PFUser
    cell.passedUser = userObject

    if userObject["profileImage"] != nil{
    let userImageFile = userObject["profileImage"] as! PFFile
    let url = NSString(string:userImageFile.url!)
    cell.profileImage.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: url as String), placeholderImage:UIImage())
    }

    if userObject["username"] != nil{
        let username = userObject["username"] as! String
        cell.labelName.text = username
    }

    //return cell
    return cell
}
```

and

```
class SpotlightCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var favouriteButton: UIButton!

    var passedUser : PFUser!
    var label : UILabel?
    var favouriteBool = false

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }

    ...

     //the IBAction was here before
}
```

Comment: please show where you are setting selector of the button.

Comment: it is a connection from the user interface (from the cell to the cell subclass)

Comment: Are you using autolayout??

Comment: Yes, in my sotyboard

Comment: @Alessandro Please check your button's width. May be it is zero due to unsatisfied constraints. And post your cell's screen shot

Comment: No, the button is clearly visible

Comment: Can the reason be that the outlet is placed in the UITableViewCell subview instead of in the UITableViewController class?

Comment: @Alessandro Post your `cellForRow` code

Comment: Make sure, you have connected it to controller class, not to custom cell class

Comment: I connected the IBAction to the controller class and it still doesn't work. See the edit

Comment: @Alessando, A IBAction from a reusable object (in this case your cell) should never be placed inside the controller class of the tableView. It should instead be placed inside the class of your custom Cell. Do you have a custom class for your custom cell? If you do, could you please show it.

Comment: Please see the edit. The action was in the custom cell class, but it didn't work even there...

Comment: have you tried programmatically adding Button in TableView?

Answer (score 0):

Simply enough, UITableViewCells have a contentView. This can and will be placed in front of other views in your custom table view cells in order to pick up touches and detect cell selection. In doing so, it may block touches to any views behind it. Fixed the error by doing cell.contentView.addSubview(cell.favouriteButton).

Note that in my storyboard the favouriteButton was already shown as a subview of the contentView, so this might lead you into thinking that it is a subview of it. For some reason, it is not.